# Distilled honey spirit needs an official name

Tags: fermentation, mead, honey, distillation

I am relatively new to the world of personal home brewing. I have always gravitated towards mead and my next venture ought to be distilling some.

I've read through lots of articles and threads on the topic and to no end have I found something agreed upon on the issue.
Every other spirit has its own category based on its original ingredient, the process, or a slice of historical origin.
Why on earth has distilled honey ferment not have a name of its own?
Fermented honey is generally considered the most far back dated form of alcohol documented, yet the distillation of fermented honey is extremely uncommon for some reasons and there doesn't seem to be an officially recognized name.
I really just wanted to give my vote and leave the conversation to others to explore.

If there were to ever be an adopted name for the spirit, I vote it be called Nectar.
It has connotations to the source of the product as well as the mythos of fermented honey in Greek poetry "nectar of the gods". What a befitting name for the concoction in my opinion. I'd love to see what others feel about this name as well as the issue itself.
Also, why aren't honey spirits really a common product at this point? I live in USA so maybe there are some in other regions that im not aware of.

Comment: Midas..honeydew...spirit..somel...nectar...[obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: Have a look here: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/what-do-you-get-if-you-distill-mead

Comment: Since its basic ingredient is a natural sugar, could it be a variety of rum?  (I *do* like the name "nectar" though.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer, but this guy calls it "comb vodka":
[distilled honey = comb vodka](https://www.liquor.com/articles/liquor-made-from-honey/)